After hibernate update SQL syntax error is raised in SQL request in Spring Data
I have a query
@Query(value = """
SELECT cast((
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) * 3600 * 1000 +
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) * 60 * 1000 +
  EXTRACT(SECOND FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) * 1000 +
  EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started))) as long)
FROM JobFile jf
LEFT JOIN jf.job j
WHERE j.finished >= :date
AND j.status = 2
AND jf.advancedProcessing = :advanced
""")
Long getAverageTimeAdvanced(@Param("date") Date date, @Param("advanced") boolean b);

I face the following exception after update:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Date org.epo.cc.file.malwareinspector.hibernate.repository.JobRepository.getAverageTimeAdvanced(java.util.Date,boolean)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:60)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111)
… 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SyntaxException: At 1:218 and token ‘FROM’, no viable alternative at input ‘SELECT cast((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) \* 3600 \* 1000 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) \* 60 \* 1000 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) \* 1000 + EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS \*FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started))) as date) FROM JobFile jf LEFT JOIN jf.job j WHERE j.finished \>= :date AND j.status = 2 AND jf.advancedProcessing = :advanced’ \[SELECT cast((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) \* 3600 \* 1000 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) \* 60 \* 1000 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) \* 1000 + EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started))) as date) FROM JobFile jf LEFT JOIN jf.job j WHERE j.finished \>= :date AND j.status = 2 AND jf.advancedProcessing = :advanced\]

CREATE TABLE job_file (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    status INT NOT NULL,
    allowed INT NOT NULL,
    job_id UUID NOT NULL,
    file_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    file_path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    uid VARCHAR(255),
    mdc_data_id VARCHAR(32),
    mdc_server VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES job(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES uploaded_file(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE job (
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    status INT NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    callbackurl VARCHAR(255),
    source VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE job ADD COLUMN started TIMESTAMP;

@UpdateTimestamp @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) @Column(name = "updated", updatable = true) private Date updated;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) @Column(name = "started", updatable = true) private Date started;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) @Column(name = "finished", updatable = true) private Date finished;

Would be grateful for a hint
Revert shows no errors. Tried to change cast - no luck so far

My comment is the same as the last time you asked this question: cast( ...) has no actual cast. See Type Casts for what is expected. This ... as long) is not  it long is not a type.   Also  the extract's can be boiled down to EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM AVG(j.finished - j.started)) * 1000 if you are looked for an answer in milliseconds.
